# Feed filenames from txt file into a windows findstr command

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, findstr

I have a file named `AAA.txt` with the following content:

> ```
> text_file1.txt
> text_file2.txt
> text_file3.txt
> ```

I want to try and use the `findstr` command (form is: `findstr "string" file`) In such a way that it will look for the string `hello world` from the files `text_file1.txt`, `text_file2.txt` and `text_file3.txt`.

I know I can do: `findstr "hello world" text_file*.txt` for the same effect, but how can I use the `AAA.txt` for the exact same result?

Side note: not allowed to use `grep`.

Comment: Type **`findstr/?`** into a **cmd.exe** window and read the output.

Comment: For example, how about this? `cmd /c for /f "delims=" %a in (AAA.txt) do findstr "hello world" %a`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i need.

Comment: `findstr "hello world"` will find anything, that contains `hello` or `world` or something like `The world says hello`. Use `findstr /c:"hello world"`to find the exact string. You may also be interested in the `/i` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new command prompt (`cmd`) instance, type `findstr /?` and read the help very carefully.

You will find the `/F` option of the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), which is what you are looking for, I guess:

```cmd
findstr /F:"AAA.txt" "hello world"
```

This will search all files listed in `AAA.txt` for the strings `hello` and `world` and returns every line containing a match, preceded by the name/path of the corresponding file and a colon (`:`).

Note that the files listed by name in `AAA.txt` are searched in the current working directory. You need to specify their paths in case they are located somewhere else.

If you want to search for the exact string `hello world`, you need to change the command line:

```cmd
findstr /F:"AAA.txt" /C:"hello world"
```

For perfroming case-insensitive searches, add the `/I` option:

```cmd
findstr /I /F:"AAA.txt" /C:"hello world"
```

In case you are only interested on the names/paths of the files containing a match, add `/M`:

```cmd
findstr /M /I /F:"AAA.txt" /C:"hello world"
```